# .arff files with scikit-learn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, weka, arff

I would like to use an [Attribute-Relation File Format](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/arff.html) with scikit-learn to do some NLP task, is this possible? How can use an `.arff` file with `scikit-learn`?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I really recommend [liac-arff](https://github.com/renatopp/liac-arff). It doesn't load directly to numpy, but the conversion is simple:

```
import arff, numpy as np
dataset = arff.load(open('mydataset.arff', 'rb'))
data = np.array(dataset['data'])
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Any idea of how can i use this conversation to classify?.

Comment: I all ready know that for instance with SVM the basic idea for classification is:`from sklearn import svm
s = svm.SVC()
lables = [label1, label2]    
s.fit(training_data, labels)` How could i present an `arff` file to a classification algorithm?

Comment: Were you able parse TF-IDF scores from .arff file and use it in sklearn?

Comment: I get the following exception when loading an arff file using liac-arff:
`BadAttributeType: Bad @ATTRIBUTE type, at line 21.`
I think the reason is the presence of "relational" attributes in my arff file. Has anyone a solution? Thank you.

Answer (score 11):

I found that scipy has a loader for arff files [`loadarff()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.arff.loadarff.html) to load them as numpy record arrays. I am not 100% sure that those arrays are suitable for direct consumption by scikit-learn but that should get your started.

Comment: Do you think i'll need to parse those numpy arrays?... What kind of preprocess would i need to do in order to feed some classification algorithm in scikit-learn?

Comment: Those looking for code to use scipy                                                                                                                                                                       
import  scipy.io.arff as arff 
data = arff.loadarff(open(file_path,'rt'))

Answer (score 6):

Solution with `scipy.arff`

**Code:**

```py
from scipy.io import arff
import pandas as pd

data = arff.loadarff('file.arff')
df = pd.DataFrame(data[0])
df.head()
```

Comment: This is the preferred solution if you don't want additional dependencies. +1

Answer (score 3):

Follow renatopp's answer:
assume your data is the iris dataset, there should be 5 dimensional with last one is the class label column.

```
s = svm.SVC()
data_input = data[:,0:4]
labels = data[:,4] # this is the class column
s.fit(data_input, labels)
```

I think this is something you want.

Answer (score 0):

If your "arff" file is a text file, try the following code instead:

```
import arff, numpy as np
dataset = arff.loads(open('mydataset.arff', 'rt'))
data = np.array(dataset['data'])
```